# Singular vectors of sums of outer products

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, svd, singular-values

I have a symmetric PSD matrix

$$ P = \sum_{i = 1}^N p_ip_i^\top \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} $$

where $p_i \in \mathbb{R}^n\ \forall i$. Its SVD is $P = U\Sigma_pU^\top$. I also have another sum

$$A = \sum_{i = 1}^N a_ip_i^\top \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$$

where $a_i \in \mathbb{R}^m\ \forall i$, with SVD $A = V_1\Sigma_aV_2^\top$. There's no relationship between $a_i$ and $p_i$ (actually, in my particular application, all the $a_i$ are random vectors that are independent of $p_j\ \forall j \leq i$).

Obviously, there should be no relationship between $U$ and $V_1$. Given that both $A$ and $P$ have $p_i^\top$ on the right sides of their respective unitary matrices, though, is there a relationship between $U$ and $V_2$? Perhaps even between $\Sigma_p$ and $\Sigma_a$ (where this relationship might need to be expressed in terms of all the $a_i$)?

Comment: Why the same notation for matrices and integers?

Comment: What do you call a "dyad" ? An ordered pair ?

Comment: Yes, I used dyad to mean a rank-1 matrix, but I just removed that word from the body in case it's confusing. Also, Rodrigo, I'm not sure what you mean by the same notation for matrices and integers since there are no integers involved here (except for the indices in the sums). But I did clarify in the question that all the $a_i$ and $p_i$ are vectors.

Comment: @Iascaire What is $N$?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo $N$ is any integer $\geq 1$. If $N = 1$ then $U = V_2$ pretty trivially, so I suppose I'm mostly interested in the case when $N \in \mathbb{N} : N > 1$.